# Calling a web service from a Visualforce page using jQuery Ajax

Tags: visualforce, jquery, ajax, httprequest, httpresponse

I want to call a web service using REST API from the Visualforce page. Below is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function(){

        $j('.queryBtn').click(function(){
            $j.ajax({
                url: "https://my.api.example",
                type: "GET",
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("api_token","23H4HHH34J");
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
                },
                success: function(res) {
                    alert(" success response : " + res);
                },
                error: function(res) {
                    alert(" failure response : " + res);
                }
            });

        });


    });

</script>
<button class="queryBtn">Login</button>
```

I added the url endpoint to the remote site settings. But I end up getting three errors:

1. the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
2. Origin https://c.na15.visual.force.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
3. [Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://my.api.example. Origin https://c.na15.visual.force.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I have never done this before and i am following these online tutorials to guide me. I was successfully able to make an API call to the same endpoint using Apex so I know it works in 100% apex code.

http://www.oyecode.com/2014/02/how-to-salesforce-rest-api-from-browser.html

One thing I know for sure is that it is a GET request. So I do not know why it shows 405 (method not allowed).

Any suggestions on how I can perform a GET request from JS on a Visualforce page without involving any apex code?

Comment: Have you added "https://my.api.example" in remote site settings?

Comment: Yes I did. I was successfully able to make an API call to the same endpoint using Apex.

Comment: I am on a developer edition. We are doing a proof-of-concept for one of our web integrations.